# How to calculate MARGIN in Tableau

Tags: tableau-api

I'm trying to calculate margin as usual but Tableau would not calculate simple fraction and as a result of calc shows 0.

Here is how I'm doing to get the result

```
IF [Scenario]="(Fact)"
Then (([2.1.4. Sales]+[3.1.5. Cost)/[2.1.4. Sales])
END
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you show us some actual sample data? And some outliers, like when any of the values can be null.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose the problem is that the calculation uses wrong Number Forrmat.

You need to do the following

- Right click calculation in measures bar
- Select Default Properties -> Number Format ...
- Choose Number (custom)
- Click OK